# Better way to do array addition in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

Code

```
use List::MoreUtils 'pairwise'; # http://stackoverflow.com/a/1865966/54964
my @offset = (0.28)x scalar(@x); # http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=110603
my @x = pairwise { $a + $b } @x, @offset;
```

I would like find a better way to this by default tools.

Is there any better way to do array addition in Perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for a pairwise array summation here: That is an issue created your choice to create a second array as big as the original one (at least doubling the memory footprint of your program).

All you are doing is to add a constant to every element of `@x`. Use a `for` loop:

```
$_ += 0.28 for @x;
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I like to keep the memory footprint constant.

Comment: What is the difference between this command and your command in the comment with the map?  I think both have the same memory footprint, just different implementation of two commands. Actually, the command in the comment does not seem to work in my system.

Comment: This command *@x = map $_ += 0.28, @x;* produces the same as the command in your answer. Without *@x = ...*, no storage. My Perl is 5.18.2 so new one.

Answer (score 2):

First make it work, then make it better. Or in other words, avoid premature optimization.

```
my $offset = 0.28;
for my $x_value ( @x ){
    $x_value += $offset;
}
```

Simple means those who have to maintain your code will like you. ☻